# Reformat LWC (Lightning Web Component) Input to Credit Card formatting

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I have a Lightning Input that when a user types into I would like it to be reformatted to mirror CC Credit Card formatting. For example when I type in 1234567812345678 it updates as the user is typing to 1234-5678-1234-5678. I have a function that is able to reformat the a value to represent this formatting. I am having an issue displaying the newly formatted value.

HTML

```
                    <div onkeyup={anKeyUp}>
                        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="false" vertical-align="end">
                            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="10" medium-device-size="8"
                                large-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
                                <div class="slds-form-element">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                        <lightning-input type="search" label="Account Number" onchange={handleSearchTerm}
                                            data-id="ANS" value={cardNumberFormating}>
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="2" medium-device-size="2"
                                large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                                <lightning-button label="Search" variant="brand" onclick={handleCMSearch}>
                                </lightning-button>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
                    </div>
```

When the search term is changed it calls a "handleSearchTerm" Js. This is used to capture the value that will be used for the actual search. Within this JS I am calling my reformatting function and then attempting to display the new reformatted value onto the input.

JS

```
    @track cardNumberFormating = '';
    strSearchTerm = '';

    // Search Term Handler
    handleSearchTerm(event) {

        console.log('Handling Search Term Update...');
        this.strSearchTerm = event.detail.value;
        console.log('Search Term: ', event.detail.value);
        this.reformat(this.strSearchTerm);

    }

    // Reformating Functionality
    reformat(value){

        // Goal to reformat card search func to look like CC format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
        console.log(value);

        var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
        var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
        var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
        var parts = []
        for (i=0, len=match.length; i<len; i+=4) {
            parts.push(match.substring(i, i+4))
        }
        if (parts.length) {
            return parts.join(' ')
        } else {
            this.cardNumberFormating = value;
        }

    }
```

I am getting a very generic error when typing into the search bar and it looks like its failing on the return of the reformat function.

Solution/Resolution:

```
    // Reformating Functionality
    reformat(value){

        // Goal to reformat card search func to look like CC format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
        console.log(value);

        var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
        var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
        var match = matches && matches[0] || '';
        var parts = [];
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<match.length; i+=4) {
            parts.push(match.substring(i, i+4))
        }

        if(parts.length) {
            this.cardNumberFormating = parts.join('-');
        } else {
            this.cardNumberFormating = value;
        }

        console.log('Formatted Card Number: ', this.cardNumberFormating);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `i` variable in the `for` loop or `format` method is not declared which is causing the error, atleast on my system.
2. The last if-else is likely not required, you can change it to.

   ```
   this.cardNumberFormating = parts.join('-')
   ```

Comment: It was that, and a problem with the for loop. Solution Above. Thanks for your help.